# Ms Access query count first

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table:

```
tblOrder
----------------------------
OrderID       ==>Primary Key
CustomerID    ==>Number
OrderDate     ==>Date
Order         ==>Number
Price         ==>Currency
```

[Order] field contain a number (like 11, 15, 17) which is a code.

I am trying to find a way, and if it is possible of course, to count [Order] per [CustomerID] that:

```
==>  I) Placed only [Order]=15
==> ii) Made first [Order]=15 and then placed another order which IS NOT 15.

Example Table: 
OrderID  CustomerID  OrderDate  Order  Price
--------------------------------------------
   1         3        1/1/2018    15     100
   2         2        3/2/2018    15     300
   3         2        7/3/2018    11     400
   4         3        2/6/2018    15     200
   5         1        5/2/2018    17     300
   6         1       11/7/2018    15     600
   7         2        1/4/2018    11     200

OutPut Query:
CustomerID  OnlyOrder=15  FirstOrder=15
---------------------------------------
   1           Null            Null    
   2             1               3    
   3             2             Null
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see how your sample results match the conditions you have specified.

Comment: I had a small mistake. I correct it.

Comment: You are asking to count the number of customers.  You then have a table with multiple rows and it is not clear what the columns mean.  They don't appear to be counts.

Comment: You are correct again. I edit that part too.

Comment: The first column count Order=15 and the second count ONLY if the first Order was 15.

Comment: And how does Customer 2 have counts for both columns?

Comment: First column is (2) because he has [Order]=15, twice.

Comment: Second column is (3) because we are counting Order only if FIRST [Order]=15.

Comment: I need to found out, how many more orders I had from an order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is much easier using aggregation and `having`.  The following gets the customers:

```
select customerId
from tblOrders
group by customerId
having min(iif([order] = 15, orderdate, null)) < max(iif([order] <> 15, orderdate, null)) or
       (min([order]) = 15 and max(order = 15));
```

To count them, use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select customerId
      from tblOrders
      group by customerId
      having min(iif([order] = 15, orderdate, null)) < max(iif([order] <> 15, orderdate, null)) or
             (min([order]) = 15 and max([order]) = 15)
     ) as c;
```

Edit:

If you want the *first* order to be 15 --which is not how I interpret the description -- that is also easy:

```
select customerId
from tblOrders
group by customerId
having min(iif([order] = 15, orderdate, null)) = min(orderdate) or
       (min([order]) = 15 and max(order = 15));
```

You can use this to count the customer ids.

EDIT:

For the revised question, you want something like this:

```
select customerId,
       iif(min([order]) = 15 and max(order = 15), count(*), 0) as all_first_15,
       iif(min(iif([order] = 15, orderdate, null)) = min(orderdate) and min([order]) <> max([order]), count(*), 0) as first_order_15
from tblOrders
group by customerId
having min(iif([order] = 15, orderdate, null)) = min(orderdate) or
       (min([order]) = 15 and max(order = 15));
```

Comment: You added OrderDate which for the moment I don't need it.

Comment: @YvetteLee . . . How do you determine the ordering of the products, say to define "first"?

Comment: First Order of the CustomerID. First Order will be also the First OrderDate, unless the table is filter by a different column. So, I need to add OrderDate for safe results.

Comment: The use of `iif` in the aggregates is very smart, I forgot about that. This answer certainly is more efficient than mine, if it works. Note that mine assumes first is first entered (lowest OrderID)

Comment: Note that your current query only checks min and max to check if they're all 15. You better adjust that to check if the count for not 15 is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, that's quite a set of rules, but certainly possible.

Let's start with a subquery:

Select all customers where the first order (the order with the lowest (minimal) OrderID) is 15:

```
SELECT t.CustomerID 
FROM tblOrder t 
WHERE t.Order = 15 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM tblOrder i 
    WHERE t.CustomerID = i.CustomerID 
    HAVING Min(i.OrderID) = t.OrderID
)
```

Then, we can use that to count all orders for these users:

```
SELECT Count(OrderID)
FROM tblOrder c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tblOrder t 
    WHERE t.Order = 15 
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM tblOrder i 
        WHERE t.CustomerID = i.CustomerID 
        HAVING Min(i.OrderID) = t.OrderID
    )
    AND t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
)
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
```

Or, if you want to split out counts by 15 and not 15:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.CustomerID, (SELECT COUNT(s2.OrderID) FROM tblOrder s2 WHERE s2.CustomerID = o.CustomerID AND s2.Order = 15) As Only15Count, (SELECT COUNT(s1.OrderID) FROM tblOrder s1 WHERE s1.CustomerID = o.CustomerID AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblOrder s3 WHERE s3.CustomerID = s1.CustomerID AND s3.Order <> 15)) As TotalCount
FROM tblOrders o
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tblOrder t 
    WHERE t.Order = 15 
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM tblOrder i 
        WHERE t.CustomerID = i.CustomerID 
        HAVING Min(i.OrderID) = t.OrderID
    )
    AND t.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
)
```

Note that, in contrast to your expected output, nothing will get returned if the first order isn't 15.

Comment: At your last example  "SELECT COUNT(s2.OrderID) FROM tblOrder s2 WHERE s2.CustomerID = o.CustomerID AND Order = 15)"

Comment: <Message> in query expression <expression>. (Error 3075)

Comment: Seems like you're missing the opening parenthesis there. I'll make the scope of order explicit, that might cause trouble too.

Comment: Again the same but now from "SELECT 1...until the end" same error

Comment: Strange... it is working but I am not taking the output I prefer.

Comment: Eh... Whaddayamean? What's wrong with the output? Perhaps edit the question

Comment: TotalOrder is part II in my question.

Comment: Need to count order where customer placed an order 15 first.

Comment: check CustomerID=3, it has only Order=15 (x2)

Comment: Well... See the edit. Changing the order of columns is pretty basic

Comment: TotalCount = count order where 15 was placed first.

Comment: Well... If you have 2x order = 15, the first order placed is 15. The second one too. So that results in 2.

Comment: correct but I need to see which customer order something else after 15.

Comment: if i sell milk, I need to find out how many customer bought something else too

Comment: Ah, yes. See the edit. The question is getting quite broad, many separate issues to tackle.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's getting a bit late for me, fixed